# why it affects former one?

Tags: javascript, html, innertext

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Momentum</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="greeting" class="hello">
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>did you find me?</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      let a = document.querySelector("#greeting div div h1");
      console.log(a);
      a.innerText = "I got you!";
      console.log(a);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Expected console result :

```
<h1>did you find me?</h1>
<h1>I got you!</h1>
```

Actual result :

```
<h1>I got you!</h1>
<h1>I got you!</h1>
```

Can you explain why first console result has changed?